# Output LFTP result to variable

Tags: bash, lftp

How do I save `LFTP` result in a variable so I can use it later in my script.

This is the basic command I have:

`lftp -c 'open -e "mirror /path/to/remote /path/to/local/" ftp://username:password@ftp.domain.com:21'`

This obviously this doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

output=""
lftp -c 'open -e "mirror /path/to/remote /path/to/local/" ftp://username:password@ftp.domain.com:21' > $output
echo "Test: " $output
```

**EDIT:**

It seems the problem is using `lftp -c` doesn't create any output. Therefore the variable is empty. So the problem is to get output from `lftp`.

Comment: Look up `how to save output of command to variable bash`. It has been answered multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Command Substitution` to store the output of a command in a variable:

```
output=`lftp -c 'open -e "mirror /path/to/remote /path/to/local/" ftp://username:password@ftp.domain.com:21'`
echo "Test: ${output}"
```